# MATLAB memory management of indexing of sparse matrices in system of equations

Tags: matlab, memory-management, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to know how MATLAB does memory management for the following system of equations that includes indexing of the sparse matrix.

```
x = A(indices,indices) \ b(indices);
```

`A` is a sparse symmetric matrix, `b` is a column-vector, `indices` has the index of the elements of `A` to be included in the system of equations `Ax = b`.

I think `A` is stored as a `CSC` (compressed sparse column). It is then stored temporarily in the memory with a different `CSC` data. The new `CSC` is finally used in the system of equations with `b(indices)`, similar to the following:

```
Aindexed = A(indices,indices); % New symmetric sparse matrix
bindexed = b(indices);
x = Aindexed \ bindexed;
```

Does MATLAB have special sparse solvers with matrix indexing? I think it's less likely that MATLAB does the indexing inside the solver and the sparse matrix has to be indexed prior to being used in the solver. These are just my guesses. Could someone kindly shed some light on this subject? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sparse linear solvers usually use storage schemes based either on linked lists or on adjacency structures. The first is more flexible, allowing easy inclusion of new elements, compression, etc. The second scheme is economical in terms of RAM requirements, and also provides better performance for the processing algorithms, but inclusion/exclusion of elements is not possible. You can find more information and ask specific questions if you visit the following blog: http://comecau.blogspot.com/2018_09_05_archive.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you provide an example for the linked list with inclusion or compression of elements?

Comment: I would probably suggest that you consider finding an elaborate answer in one of classic books devoted to sparse matrices, for example: "Sparse Matrices Technology" by Sergio Pissanetzky (the first two pages of Chapter 1) or "Computer Solutions of Large Sparse Positive Definite Systems" by Alan George and Joseph W-H Liu (paragraph 3.2). Alternatively, if you are looking for working codes, here is a publication with codes on CD: https://www.amazon.com/Solution-Systems-Algebraic-Equations-Matrices/dp/0646990454

Comment: Thank you. When you say compression of the elements do you mean `matrix indexing`, e.g., https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?

Comment: If a sparse matrix is stored by means of linked list, compression doesn't occur by physically removing one element from the matrix. Instead, what is modified is the reference. Let, say, in the linked list for a particular column of the matrix, the elements themselves are stored in a[] array, their row indexes in lin[] array, and references to the next non-zero element in next[] array. Removal of a particular element is made by modifying the next[] component to "after the next", so the element to-be-removed is just "jumped over".